# Using Full Featured textAngular extra features

Tags: angularjs, rich-text-editor

I've downloaded textAngular from here:

https://github.com/mfrye/textAngular

And all i want is the extra features of color-picker and font-size/family,
This is my scripts links:

```
<script src=[[asset('vendor/textAngular-master/textAngular-sanitize.min.js')]]></script>
<script src=[[asset('vendor/textAngular-master/textAngular.min.js')]]></script>
```

And i turn it on like this:

```
<text-angular ng-model="quest.txt"></text-angular>
```

Now in my toolbar i see the default ones(The ones in the list here:https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar)
How can i see/use the extra ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, global and instance.

- For details on the global options see here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Setting-Defaults. (It's the taToolbar option)
- If you are setting it on one instance only use the 'ta-toolbar' attribute as shown here: `<text-angular ta-toolbar="[['h1','h2','h3'],['bold','italics','colourRed']]"></text-angular>`

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't seem to list all the available buttons/options, including color and font picker; so, I don't see how any of the current answers address the exact question.  Maybe I'm just not being observant enough.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all the textAngular options you can find them here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Directives. I had trouble finding this information under the heading "Directives" though, technically, that's exactly what they are.

Simeon (who provided the accepted answer to this question) is actively developing textAngular and is a great resource.